# jQuery tree traversal from child to closest filtered parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code snippet from an html page:

```
<td class="alltablergt ">
    <div class="allocsz">
        <table class="table-allocsz">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
    <td>
<div class="sigle-sz">
    <span class="label-sz">36</span>
    <input class="size-quantity" type="tel" value="" name="" >
    <div class="available yes"><i aria-hidden="true" class="availablespot"></i></div>
</div>
```

I am in the input element "size-quantity" and I would reach the "alltablergt" element.

If $this is the size-quantity element, I thought the way to reach the "alltablergt" element was:

```
$(this).parentsUntil(".alltablergt")
```

but this doesen't work.
How can I reach it?

Comment: var alltablergt = $(this).closest(body).find('.alltablergt'), in place of body, you call parent of both the divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `closest()`.

```js
$('.size-quantity').closest(".alltablergt").addClass('highlight');
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alltablergt ">
  <div class="allocsz">
    <table class="table-allocsz">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="sigle-sz">
              <span class="label-sz">36</span>
              <input class="size-quantity" type="tel" value="" name="">
              <div class="available yes"><i aria-hidden="true" class="availablespot"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```